# Lock editing on node except for Admin

Tags: nodes, rules, users

I have a content type with a select field. When the selected value from that field is "Locked", I would like to lock editing on that node for all roles except admin (or other role I choose to be admin). Then if the admin selects a different value, I would like to unlock editing on the node. For this reason it seems that rules are the best way to trigger an action like this. I have the content access module installed, which allows targeted access permission both for content types, and individual nodes. But how can I combine the two parts to lock editing automatically based on the select list? If I couldn't do it automatically, is there some way to restrict all access per node?

Edit:
This is possible with Rules and content access. There is an action provided by the content access module which will revoke access to a node based on role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could accomplish this with a combination of rules and user roles. I assume to don't want the node to be editable by anonymous users so set the rule to grant editing permissions to all users who have a particular role when the value of the field changes from locked to unlocked (or whatever your corresponding value is). If you want more granular control, (i.e. when a node is unlocked some fields are editable but others remain editable only by admin users), you'll need to install the field permissions module (https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions.

Comment: This totally worked. Not sure why I didn't think it wasn't possible with just rules, but there is a "Revoke access by role" action, which I'm assuming comes from content access! Thanks so much!